# How to search for joint chat in new Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

My company is using [New Teams](https://adoption.microsoft.com/en-us/new-microsoft-teams/#:%7E:text=New%20Teams%20now%20has%20full,a%20channel%20conversation%2C%20and%20more.) for internal chat, and I'm having trouble using it to find earlier group chats. I can search for a chat I had with just Mo and find it, but when I search for 'Mo and Larry' in the search bar at the top of Teams chat, I don't find the group chat. Or is there a way to search for *any* chat that includes Mo and find a chat with just Mo, with Mo and Larry, and with Mo Larry and Curly?